# print javascript code in php is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to add this javascript in php echo

```
<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('footerSlideContainer').style.display ='block'">ddddddd</a>
```

i tried this  but not working

```
 echo "  
  <a  href=\"javascript://\" onClick=\"clearChildren(document.getElementById('row11'));\" > <img src='Dealer/images/email_send.png'   style='width:22px;height:22px' />
  Contact Advertiser </a>" ;
```

Comment: What does it print? Those `onClick`s are different

Comment: Why would somebody downvote a perfectly valid question from a newbie?

Comment: actually i want to print this code on tooltip.but its not showing on tooltip its showing on form

Comment: echo javascript and above javascript is different then what you have to print

Comment: @MarsOne: most likely someone downvoted because they thought that not enough effort was placed to attempt to see what's wrong with their code (I didn't vote on this post).

Comment: acutally what i tried its just a format if i am adding any javascript code there its showing that on page not on tooltip

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, Atleast the Op has bothered to debug part of the code and has posted something that he feel's maybe the problem. lets give him credit for that. Check this question for an example of total lame behaviour.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651488/html-moving-when-resizing-browser#comment29179984_19651488

Comment: @MarsOne: I can't do anything about the other person's downvote - they're entitled to their opinion and to vote accordingly. I'm simply speculating on possible reasons why one would do so.

Comment: i Get that. Just trying to defend the OP from haters on SO

Comment: tried this also   echo "  
  <a  href=\"javascript://\" onClick=\"clearChildren(document.getElementById('footerSlideContainer').style.display ='block');\" > <img src='Dealer/images/email_send.png'   style='width:22px;height:22px' />
  Contact Advertiser </a>" ;

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you tell me what you are trying to do? Need more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo "<a  href=\"javascript://\" onClick=\"document.getElementById('footerSlideContainer').style.display ='block'\" > <img src='Dealer/images/email_send.png'   style='width:22px;height:22px' /> Contact Advertiser </a>"; ?>
```

try this code. problem is your javascript code in onClick event. what you want to do?

```
document.getElementById('footerSlideContainer').style.display ='block';
```

or

```
clearChildren(document.getElementById('row11'));
```

If you want 1st one copy my code, else there is nothing wrong with your code. That means bug on clearChildren(), check clearChildren() is defined and works perfectly.